# set image expiry date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an e-commerce site where people usually uploads images in order to set images on product items.`For example: A person who need his photo on the cake can upload his picture`.Now what i was thinking is there any way to add an expiry date on an image.Which actually delete images after that time.

If it is possible how do i achieve that ?

if this is not possible then do i have to add some info inside the properties of the image such as the expiry time and later on  running a script through images folder deleting  those images whose time has expired ?

If none of them are possible what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your point right, you want to clean up your image folders automatically.

No, it is not possible to tell a file to "self-delete" after some time.
You have to set up a cronjob, which scans the folder and does the deleting for you.

Create a PHP file with this code on your server and execute it e.g. every day by a cronjob.

```
<?php
//Folder containing all images
$dir = '/my/image/folder/';
//max age for an image (in seconds)
//    2592000sec = 30days
$delafter = 2592000;
$imgs = scandir( $dir );
foreach( $imgs as $img ){
 if( $img != '.' && $img != '..' ){
    $age = filemtime( $dir.'/'.$img );
    if( ( $age + $delafter ) < time() ){
        if( unlink( $dir.'/'.$img ) ){
            $log[] = 'Deleted: '.$img;
        }
        else{
            $log[] = 'Error deleting:'.$img;
        }
    }
    else{
        $log[] = 'Left: '.$img;
    }
  }
}
header( 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8' );
echo implode( "\r\n", $log );
?>
```

If not all images should be deleted after the same time, you could have different folders or you can save the `$delafter` for each file in a database.